# Destructure and process vector of hash-maps in Clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, key-value, destructuring

I have a vector of hash-maps, like this:

```
(def my-maps [{:a 1} {:b 2}])
```

I want to loop over each hash-map, give the key and value a more meaningful name within the loop, then process each hash-map differently depending on its key.

Without further ado, here is my best attempt:

```
(for [m my-maps]
  (let [my-key-name (key m) my-val-name (val m)]
    (case my-key-name
      :a (println "Found key :a with value " my-val-name)
      :b (println "Found key :b with value " my-val-name))))
```

This approach, however, produces a rather cryptic error:

```
; Error printing return value (ClassCastException) at clojure.core/key (core.clj:1569).
; class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap cannot be cast to class java.util.Map$Entry (clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.Map$Entry is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On each execution of the `for`'s body, `m` is bound to a map. `key` and `val` functions expect a map _entry_, not the map itself. Try re-binding `m` to `(first m)` if you're sure that each map has one and only one element.

Comment: And to use destructuring, you can simply `(let [[my-key my-val] (first m)] ...)` since a map entry is an indexed collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can destructure inside [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) (or use [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq)):

```
(for [[[k v] & _] [{:a 1} {:b 2}]]
  (println "Found key" k "with value" v))

Found key :a with value 1
Found key :b with value 2
=> (nil nil)
```

Comment: Wow, that's way simpler and cleaner! Although, I must admit that `[[[k v] & _]` makes by brain hurt a little bit. What does `& _` mean? My best guess: "Ignore all other elements of the map," where `&` is used to capture the remaining elements (remaining arguments), and `_` is used to ignore them; sort of like in Erlang pattern matching.

Comment: @Leif - Yes- `for` iterates over all elements in the vector, `[[k v] & _]` destructures first element of collection and ignores the rest. See https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring

Comment: `[[ k v ]] & _ ]` maps to `{ :a  1 nil}` which is `[[ :a 1]nil]` the collection seq of the hash-map. Usually the hahs-map contains other key-value pairs which are caught by the `& _`, e.g.: `[ [ k v ] ] & _ ]` matches to {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}` where `k` matches to  `:a`, `v` to `1` and the rest `& _` to `[:b 2 :c 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, here is a more general answer broken down into individual steps:

```
  (let [my-maps [{:a 1} {:b 2 :c 3}]]
    (doseq [curr-map my-maps]
      (newline)
      (println "curr-map=" curr-map)
      (let [map-entries (seq curr-map)]
        (println "map-entries=" map-entries)
        (doseq [curr-me map-entries]
          (let [[k v] curr-me]
            (println "  curr-me=" curr-me "  k=" k  "  v=" v))))))
```

With result

```
curr-map= {:a 1}
map-entries= ([:a 1])
  curr-me= [:a 1]   k= :a   v= 1

curr-map= {:b 2, :c 3}
map-entries= ([:b 2] [:c 3])
  curr-me= [:b 2]   k= :b   v= 2
  curr-me= [:c 3]   k= :c   v= 3
```

A `MapEntry` object in Clojure can be treated as either a 2-element vector (accessed via `first` & `second`) or as a `MapEntry` accessed via the `key` and `val` functions.  The destructuring form:

```
(let [[k v] curr-me]
```

treats the `MapEntry` object `curr-me` as a sequence and pulls out the first 2 elements into `k` and `v`.  Even though it prints like a vector (eg `[:a 1]`), it does have the type `clojure.lang.MapEntry`.

---

The destructuring syntax `& _` in the `for` expression of the original answer is a "rest args" destructuring. It causes the sequence of all `MapEntry` objects after the first one to be assigned to the variable `_`, which is then ignored in the rest of the code.